Java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/namespace/QName
I am trying to submit Excel file,I have following jars in my classpath

poi-3.9.jar


poi-ooxml-3.9.jar


poi-ooxml-schemas-3.9.jar


xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar


dom4j-1.6.1.jar

JDK1.6 OSGI
It is working fine in my local machine. But when I try to run it on linux and it published in weblogic it gives me the following error:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.xml.namespace.QName

when try it again it gives me the following error:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlBeans

I tried to
Add one line

DymanicImport-Package: *

In MAINEST.MF


change DymanicImport-Package to DynamicImport-Package (typo), or
add all needed packages to your MANIFEST.MF in Import-Package

